# Subgroups of amalgamated free product

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

My question is the following:

Suppose that we are given the amalgamated product $ G = G_1 * _{G_3} G_2 $, and subgroups $ H_i \le G_i $ for $i=1,2,3$, such that in addition $H_3$ is as large as possible - namely, $H_3 = G_3 \cap H_1 \cap H_2 $.

Is is true that $ H = H_1 * _{H_3} H_2 $ embeds as a subgroup of $G$ in the obvious way, or it there some counter-example?

The standard results in this direction require, for example, that $H_1 \cap G_3 = H_2 \cap G_3$ , which of course might not hold in general.

Comment: I suspect you could make $H$ be an HNN-extension instead. Subgroups of free products with amalgamation were classified by Karrass and Solitar. See [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1970-150-01/S0002-9947-1970-0260879-9/). The paper is not an easy read, but it should help.

Comment: @user1729 - thank you for the reference, I will definitely look into it. But - what do you mean, to make $H$ an HNN-extension? It is given as an amalgamated prodcut. (Did you mean that its image inside $G$ will become isomorphic to an HNN-extension)?

Comment: I have to say that I intuitively expect this to be true, I would be quite surprised to see a counter example.

Comment: Can't we just take $G_1 = \langle w,x,y \rangle$, $G_2 = \langle x,y,z \rangle$ both abelian (for example elementary abelian of order 8), $G_3  = \langle x,y \rangle$, $H_1 = \langle x \rangle$, $H_2 = \langle y \rangle$, $H_3 = 1$, then the subgroup generated by $H_1$ and $H_2$ is abelian, but $H_1 * H_2$ is not.

Comment: @derek - Thanks - your nice example answers the question, and proves my intuition wrong :-) By the way, is there still a counter example if we let $G_1 = H_1$ ?

Comment: If $G_1=H_1$ then $H_3 = H_2 \cap G_3$ and I think $H$ embeds naturally. You should be able to prove it by using standard normal forms for amalgamated free products using coset representatives, and choosing them such that the normal form for an element of $H$ becomes equal to its normal form as an element of $G$.